# DNS Issue: Cloudfare(1.1.1.1) not resolving, all other servers are working

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have a domainname (partyandco.nl) users can connect to the website via every DNS-Server except when they use 1.1.1.1 as their DNS Server. When using NSLookup I get these results:

```html
C:\Users\Computer>nslookup
Default Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

> server 1.1.1.1
Default Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

> www.partyandco.nl
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to one.one.one.one timed-out
> server 8.8.8.8
Default Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

> www.partyandco.nl
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.partyandco.nl
Address:  37.97.223.171

>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, dnsspy.io couldn't find any issues with the DNS-Settings. The settings are the same for more as 6-months so I guess it's not the 24H thing.

Comment: You are offtopic here but when debugging DNS problems you should start by querying the authoritative nameservers first. Querying recursive ones comes after that. Here you are just showing you can not reach CloudFlare public DNS resolver which can come from multiple reasons, you need to ask your sysadmin or your ISP. This could help you in that direction too: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/have-problems-with-1-1-1-1-read-me-first/15902

Comment: Every other website works fine with 1.1.1.1 it's only Partyandco.nl that is not working with 1.1.1.1

Comment: Ask your DNS provider then, as the problem is not in your DNS settings (https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.partyandco.nl)  but more around reachability to your authoritative nameservers